# UIView class getting called in the end of the loop

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiview

I am new to swift programming and was testing some scenarios.

I have a UIView class which I am using for drawing something. I will be adding this UIView class as a subview to my main viewcontroller multiple times using a for loop.

I have an entity in coredata which stores the configuration information of the Drawing which I do using the UIVIew class. Each entry will have details like ID, Diamension and some other details required for drawing.

After fetching the data from coredata, I am using a 'for' loop to iterate through each entries and then draw (UIView class as subview) using the data retrieved from coredata.

Each iteration of the loop need to create new subview using UIView class with dimensions and other details retrieved from the coredata. But I noticed that it loops through all entries and calls UIView class in the end of the loop even though .addsubView is in the middle of loop.

I can see it creates the same number of subviews as the core data entries, but since the view is getting called in the end of the loop, all subviews are getting created with the details of last entry core data.

My code is some thing like this. Please help me on this. thanks.

Main view controller.

```
   let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Projects")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if results.count > 0 {
            GlobalVariable.sharedManager.starty = 50
            for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
        let titleout = String(item.valueForKey("title")!)
                    let startxp1 = item.valueForKey("startx")
                    let startxp2 = item.valueForKey("starty")
        let projtag = item.valueForKey("pid")

        GlobalVariable.sharedManager.title = titleout 
                let DrawLanes = DrawProj(frame: CGRect(x: startx, y: starty, width: 500, height: 200))
                DrawLanes.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                DrawLanes.userInteractionEnabled = true
        DrawLanes.tag = projtag 
                MainScroller.addSubview(DrawLanes)

            }
        }
    }catch {
        print ("there was an error in fetch")
    }
```

DrawProj

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let button = UIButton(type: .System) // let preferred over var here
    button.frame = CGRectMake(24, 15, 300, 20)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    button.userInteractionEnabled = false
button.text = GlobalVariable.sharedManager.title
    self.addSubview(button)

}
```

Comment: I guess while iterating through the array NSManagedObject, the item is also a managed object type which is a reference type variable. So even if it iterates through the array, being reference type, only final value will be used.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't contain any loops, even though a loop is a key part of your question.

Comment: @Tom Harrington actually I am iterating though the NSManagedObject and adding the UIView as subview within that loop.

Comment: @snjmhj So could you please guide me how to solve this, will storing the coredata values into separate arrays first and then iterate through them will help?

Comment: @VijeshKk I might be wrong with my previous answer. I think the point of failure is the GlobalVariable.sharedManager.title = titleout and instantiating the view doesnot mean its drawRect will be called. My solution would be making a new variable in DrawLanes and initializing variable with the titleout and in the drawRect put the button.title = self.variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point of failure is `GlobalVariable.sharedManager.title = titleout` and instantiating the view doesnot mean its drawRect will be called.

My solution would be making a new variable in `DrawLanes` and initializing variable with the titleout

`DrawLines.buttonTitle = titleout`

and in the drawRect put

`button.title = self.buttonTitle`